# Custom theme colors not applying in MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a theme using MUI and the custom colors aren't applying to some of my components.

Here's the theme:

```js
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

...

const theme = createTheme({
    typography: {
        fontSize: 16,
        fontFamily: [
            "Inter",
            "-apple-system",
            "BlinkMacSystemFont",
        ].join(","),
        h1: {
            fontSize: "2rem",
            fontWeight: 500,
        },
        h2: {
            fontSize: "1.5rem",
            fontWeight: 400,
        },
    },
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: "#4C5D88",
        },
        secondary: {
            main: "#DBE0EB",
        },
        tertiary: {
            main: "#F8F9FF",
        },
// Added all of the attributes here in case that was the reason it didn't work
        white: {
            light: "#FFFFFF",
            main: "#FFFFFF",
            dark: "#FFFFFF",
            contrastText: "#FFFFFF", 
        },
        error: {
            main: "#FFEED6",
        },
        errorlight: {
            main: "#DBE0EB",
        },
        success: {
            main: "#8EDCA9",
        },
        accent1: {
            main: "#3395E7", // lighter blue
        },
        accent2: {
            main: "#E3F2FF", // darker blue
        },
        accent3: {
            main: "#E86CAF", // pink
        },
    },
});
```

And it's applied with a `ThemeProvider`:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  {/* various components */}
</Theme>
```

But, when I try to do something basic, like a `<Grid>` component with `<Typography>` inside of the `ThemeProvider`, the custom colors don't apply:

```
<Grid
    item
    sx={{
        backgroundImage: "url(...)",
        color: "white", // tried this as an experiment, too
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        flexDirection: "column",
    }}
>
    <Typography variant="h1" color="white" gutterBottom>
        This text should be white.
    </Typography>
</Grid>
```

Colors like `primary` and `secondary` work just fine, but none of the custom colors do, and I can't figure out why after trying a few different things (like checking for different dark/light modes, etc). The color default is always `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);`, if that helps.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are various approaches here.

1. You could create variants for specific components that are using the desired colors right away in the theme object. (I am not providing an example since it goes a bit beyond the palette approach you are looking for).
2. You can use the [styled() utility](https://mui.com/system/styled/) in order to create a component that is utilising the desired color and import it where you need it.:

```
import { styled } from "@mui/system";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";

const WhiteTypography = styled(Typography)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: theme.palette.white.main
}));


// Import & use it somewhere
<WhiteTypography variant="h1" gutterBottom>
  This text should be white.
</WhiteTypography>
```

3. You can reference the theme object right away in your Typography component:

```
import { theme } from "../yourthemepath/theme.js";
...
<Typography
 variant="h1"
 gutterBottom
 color={theme.palette.accent1.main}
>
 This text should be accent1.main.
</Typography>
```

See it working here: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-williamson-dndbub?file=/src/App.js:527-706

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the `useTheme` hook to do this. I don't really like how it looks (I didn't want to use `sx` for this) but it gets the job done.

I had to add `color` to the theme:

```
white: {
  main: "#FFFFFF",
  color: "#FFFFFF",
},
```

And this is how I imported it:

```
import { useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

// ...

const theme = useTheme();

// ...

<Grid
    item
    sx={{
        backgroundImage: "url(...)",
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        flexDirection: "column",
    }}
>
    <Typography variant="h1" sx={{ color: theme.palette.white }} gutterBottom>
        This text should be white.
    </Typography>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Just one question, what did you do with TS? did not it complain about anything? like that `accent1` or other custom ones does not exists in the `PaletteOptions`?

Comment: @KasirBarati I was using JavaScript, sorry!

Comment: You can do away with the useTheme hook by using this format: `sx={{ color: theme => theme.palette.success.dark }}`